# Help needed with Probability Question

Tags: probability

A card is drawn at random from a deck of playing cards. If it is red, the player wins 1 dollar; if it is black, the player loses 2 dollars. Find the expected value of the game.

I think that the number of cards in the deck may have something to do with it, and the decreasing number of red cards and black cards affect the probability of the draw being black or red which in turn affect the expected value of the game. For the most part I have no idea how this is supposed to work, I have made no successful or failed attempts to solve this question because I have no knowledge to go on.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I think you may be making the problem too complicated.  A deck of playing cards probably means a standard 52-card deck, half of which are Red (the Hearts and Diamonds) and half of which are Black (the Spades and Clubs).  So then the outcome of Red or Black has a simple well-known probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected value of the game is 
$$
\sum_{a_i}a_ip(a_i),
$$
where $a_i$ is a possible payout of the game and $p(a_i)$ is the probability of that payout occuring. Applying this to your problem gives 
$$
E[X]=1\times1/2+(-2)\times 1/2=-1/2
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the number of cards in the deck relevant?

Comment: @Paul What is relevant is the ratio of red cards to black cards. I assumed that each card had a 50/50 chance of being red or black.